# If $f(x)=0$ for all but countably many points in $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

First question in text is 'Let $f$ be real-valued function on $[a,b]\ s.t.$ $f(x)=0$ for all $x\neq c_1, ... , c_n.$ Prove that $f$ is Riemann-integrable with $\int_a^bf =0 $.'

I proved this question by setting $c_0=a , c_{n+1}=b$ and using the fact that $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[c_{i-1},c_i]$ and $\int_{c_{i-1}}^{c_{i}} f =0 $ for each $i=1, ... , n+1$.

But next question is 'Is the result of first question still true if $f(x)=0$ for all but countably many points in $[a,b]$?'

I have no idea how to prove it. What should I do?

Comment: What if $f(x) =1$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Can you have countably infinitely many points in $[a,b]$ and avoid having a limit point?  What happens to the lower and upper sums around that limit point?  Also, nothing in the problem statement orders the $c_i$, so perhaps you should have $a = \min_i c_i$ and $b = \max_i c_i$.

Comment: Note this is somewhat related to [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) (also called other things like the Ruler function) being Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Pick a dense, countable subset $S \subset [a, b]$, and consider its indicator function, $$\chi_S(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}1, & x \in S \\ 0, & x \not\in S \end{array}\right.$$ What are the upper and lower Riemman sums (for any partition) of $\int_a^b \chi_S \,dx$?

Comment: You want $\chi_S(x)$ above

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I fixed the issue.